# Showing $r^2\left(\frac\theta2-\sin\frac\theta2\cos\frac\theta2\right)=\frac{r^2}{2}(\theta-\sin\theta)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, derivation-of-formulae

I derived the formula for the area of a circular segment as follows:

[image]

However, the formula I find online when using radians is: A = $\frac{r^2}{2}\bigl(\theta - \sin(\theta)\bigr)$.  Is there a simpler way of deriving the formula or can the first formula (using radians) be converted into the second?

Comment: As [Yajat's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4832481/409) shows, you were one trig identity (and a factorization) away from the online answer; good work! ... That said, please do not use images to display the content of a question (or an answer, for that matter). Images aren't searchable, nor can they be interpreted by screen-readers used by visually-impaired visitors. Instead, for everyone's benefit, write out your text and use MathJax formatting for your equations throughout. ... Cheers!

Comment: To clarify Blue's comment: it is OK to use images to display images like the pictures of circles, but it is not ok to use images to display *text*. You should type all text with MathJax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From $A = r^2(\frac{\theta}{2} - \sin(\frac{\theta}{2})\cos(\frac{\theta}{2}))$, remember that $2\sin\theta\cos\theta = \sin(2\theta)$.

Rearranging it and substituting $\theta=\frac{\theta}{2}$, we get:
$\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})\cos(\frac{\theta}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}\sin\theta$

Putting that into our area of a circular segment formula (radians), we get:

$A = r^2(\frac{\theta}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sin\theta)$

Factoring out $\frac{1}{2}$, we get

$\fbox{$A=\frac{r^2}{2}(\theta - \sin\theta)$}$